# gst-plugins-good build fails with error: ‘GLsync’ has not been declared

Tags: qt, opengl-es-2.0, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Qt plugin build fails when I am building `gst-plugins-good==1.16.2` for Raspberry Pi on another ARM machine.

I successfully built `gstreamer==1.16.2` and `gst-plugins-base==1.16.2` and `qtbase==5.13.2` but they seem incompatible with `gst-plugins-good==1.16.2`:

```
In file included from gstqtgl.h:32:0,
                 from qtwindow.h:27,
                 from moc_qtwindow.cc:10:
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/gstglfuncs.h:93:17: error: expected identifier before ‘*’ token
   ret (GSTGLAPI *name) args;
                 ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/glprototypes/sync.h:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘GST_GL_EXT_FUNCTION’
 GST_GL_EXT_FUNCTION (GLsync, FenceSync,
 ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/glprototypes/sync.h:29:39: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘GLsync’ with no type [-fpermissive]
                       GLbitfield flags))
                                       ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/gstglfuncs.h:93:24: note: in definition of macro ‘GST_GL_EXT_FUNCTION’
   ret (GSTGLAPI *name) args;
                        ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/glprototypes/sync.h:29:39: error: ‘GLsync’ declared as function returning a function
                       GLbitfield flags))
                                       ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/gstglfuncs.h:93:24: note: in definition of macro ‘GST_GL_EXT_FUNCTION’
   ret (GSTGLAPI *name) args;
                        ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/glprototypes/sync.h:31:23: error: ‘GLsync’ has not been declared
                      (GLsync sync))
                       ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/gstglfuncs.h:93:24: note: in definition of macro ‘GST_GL_EXT_FUNCTION’
   ret (GSTGLAPI *name) args;
                        ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/glprototypes/sync.h:33:23: error: ‘GLsync’ has not been declared
                      (GLsync sync))
                       ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/gstglfuncs.h:93:24: note: in definition of macro ‘GST_GL_EXT_FUNCTION’
   ret (GSTGLAPI *name) args;
                        ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/glprototypes/sync.h:35:23: error: ‘GLsync’ has not been declared
                      (GLsync sync,
                       ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/gstglfuncs.h:93:24: note: in definition of macro ‘GST_GL_EXT_FUNCTION’
   ret (GSTGLAPI *name) args;
                        ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/glprototypes/sync.h:39:23: error: ‘GLsync’ has not been declared
                      (GLsync sync,
                       ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/gstglfuncs.h:93:24: note: in definition of macro ‘GST_GL_EXT_FUNCTION’
   ret (GSTGLAPI *name) args;
                        ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/glprototypes/sync.h:43:23: error: ‘GLsync’ has not been declared
                      (GLsync sync,
                       ^
/build/snaps/full/stage/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/gstglfuncs.h:93:24: note: in definition of macro ‘GST_GL_EXT_FUNCTION’
   ret (GSTGLAPI *name) args;
                        ^
Makefile:881: recipe for target 'libgstqmlgl_la-moc_gstqsgtexture.lo' failed
```

I saw a very similar question in https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=796879 but in my code, the line they want to remove is already missing.

Instead, I removed `#define GST_GL_HAVE_GLSYNC 1` from [ext/qt/gstqtgl.h](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/1.16.2/ext/qt/gstqtgl.h#L31) and compilation succeeded.

But the comment above that line says that it should use Qt's GLsync definition so my "fix" doesn't look correct.

I'm still trying to find a proper fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that applying a patch doesn't break anything when you use it on the Raspberry Pi device.

```
diff -Naur ./src/ext/qt/gstqtgl.h ./src2/ext/qt/gstqtgl.h
--- ./ext/qt/gstqtgl.h      2019-04-19 09:16:25.000000000 +0000
+++ ./ext/qt/gstqtgl.h      2019-12-15 09:22:22.503065057 +0000
@@ -28,7 +28,6 @@
  * that we don't typedef GLsync in gstglfuncs.h */
 #include <gst/gl/gstglconfig.h>
 #undef GST_GL_HAVE_GLSYNC
-#define GST_GL_HAVE_GLSYNC 1
 #include <gst/gl/gstglfuncs.h>

 /* The glext.h guard was renamed in 2018, but some software which
```

I hope that it helps if somebody in trouble.

I will update this post if something breaks.